# EF Code First, Querying an object, int property on object is always 1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I've got a BuildingAudit class in my EF code first. This audit is associated with a Building. Each building can only ever have one active audit. But I track changes to the audit via a revision column on the class, which is a non null integer.

Every time I run an EF query. The revision always comes back as 1, even when my query includes a check for revision is equal to something other than 1. I don't understand. There is nothing in the mapping that would cause this, nothing in the POCO that would override that value after query. How can this be happening?

Here is my code:

```
BuildingAudit buildingAudit = null;
        if (revision == null)
        {
            buildingAudit = _buildingAuditService.CustomQuery().Where(x => x.BuildingId == selectedBuilding.Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Revision).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            buildingAudit = _buildingAuditService.CustomQuery().FirstOrDefault(x => x.BuildingId == selectedBuilding.Id && x.Revision == revision);
        }
```

For those wondering the CustomQuery() merely generically exposes EF's Context.Set as queryable :

```
public virtual IQueryable<TClass> Query()
    {
        return Context.Set<TClass>().AsQueryable();
    }
```

Also my POCO:

```
 public class BuildingAudit : Entity
{
    public Guid BuildingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AuditCategory> AuditCategories { get; set; }

    public Guid Auditor { get; set; }
    public virtual User Auditor { get; set; }

    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }

    public BuildingAudit()
    {
        InitializeCollections();
    }

    private void InitializeCollections()
    {
        AuditCategories = new Collection<AuditCategory>();
    }
}
```

And entity which this class inherits from just has this:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

So nothing wonky there. Yet every time I debug this query, it will go to the else statement, the revision supplied in the .Where is NOT 1 so for instance 2. Yet when the object is returned, it has a revision of 1!

Anyone have any idea?

Here are some pictures, I have to crop to hide some sensitive information, but they are from one debug run through the above pasted code:

[image]

That's from checking the revision value in the else statement, clearly showing to return audits where revision = 2 for the selected building. Then:

[image]

The returned object property has revision 1...It should also be noted that I can save values other than 1 and the database properly reflects that, but I can't seem to query anything other than 1.

**ANSWER:**

```
if (revision == null)
        {
            assessment = _hazardAssessmentService.CustomQuery().Where(x => x.LaboratoryId == selectedLab.Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Revision).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            int rev = (int) revision;
            assessment = _hazardAssessmentService.CustomQuery().FirstOrDefault(x => x.LaboratoryId == selectedLab.Id && x.Revision == rev);
        }
```

revision is nullable int in this function, but on the POCO is a plain int. Converting revision to a plain int made this stop happening. I am checking if it's null and it never would be at this part in the if, but not sure why that would cause EF to break without notifying of any error.

Comment: I can't tell from your POCO what your PK is on your BuildingAudit table. I am wondering if maybe EF can't either and is populating the objects incorrectly because of that.

Comment: It's just an ID property inherited from Entity, all my objects have that.

Comment: Also just to clarify, the table itself has the ID property correctly as the PK. And revision is just a plain column.

Comment: What does the generated query return?

Comment: You are taking always the first record so even when you have 1 & 2 as reviewion it always returns 1.

Comment: it's very interesting because your code looks perfectly fine and I cannot find any reason your code not working as expected, please let us know if you managed to solve it.

Comment: `if (revision == null)` can that be true,? If revision an integer at that point, it is a non-nullable type and the if statement will always return false

Comment: @Nikita no I'm not, that's only in the first if branch. And when I check the returned record and compare it to the DB, the ID is a Guid for whose value has 2 as the revision in the database, but the returned object is 1.

Comment: @kienct89 I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `revision` at `if (revision == null)` is an integer it will always return false because int is a non-nullable type

if you want to enable a null check use `int?` as Type

Edit:
Make sure the Type of `BuildingAudit.Revision` is the same as the revision value you check against. It seems the parser of EF does a full type check, which would be `Nullable<int>` to `int`.

Comment: Well revision is a nullable int, and the default value for a integer is 1 not 0. And I wasn't complaining about it always returning false, because it wasn't. However, your comment allowed me to figure out the answer, revision on the object itself is int. So I will mark you down. Edit your response to the real answer though.